# Sort product according to the price(mrp of products) in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**
*Sample Data* 
storeProducts = [ 
{ Pname: 'soap',
mrp: 50
},
{ Pname: 'facewash',
mrp: 30
},
{ Pname: 'shampoo',
mrp: 100
}
];

**
*I'm trying to sort the product based on storeProducts price, I have tried something can anyone let me know how to do that?*

````
  <div class="mt-4">
            <div class="column" v-if="storeProducts.length !== 0">
              <div class="control is-pulled-right">
                <div class="select">
                 <select v-model="sortBy" v-on:change="filteredProduct">
                    <option value="1">Low to High(Price)</option>
                    <option value="2">High to Low(Price)</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProductBySubCategory',
  components: {
    ProductTile,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      storeProducts: [],
      sortBy: 1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getRenamedProducts(products) {
      return products.map((prod) => {
        return {
          id: prod.id,
          title: prod.title,
          mrp: prod.mrp,
          realUnit: prod.unit,
        };
      });
    },
  },
  computed: {
     filteredProduct: function () {
      return this.storeProducts.sort((a, b) => {
      if (this.sortBy == '1') {
     return b.mrp - a.mrp;
        } else if (this.sortyBy == '2') {
         return a.mrp - b.mrp;
         }
    });
     },
  },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: can you check the value of `this` inside the sort fat arrow function, i think the value of `this` might be incorrect in that scope. Also, can you add the error that you have got?

Comment: this return the all array of objects. error message :  184:14  error    Unexpected side effect in "filteredProduct" computed property  vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
filteredProduct: function() {
  const sortBy = this.sortBy;
  return this.storeProducts.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === '1') {
      return b.mrp - a.mrp;
    } else if (sortBy === '2') {
      return a.mrp - b.mrp;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but got the same error message.

Comment: after storing this.storeProducts into variable error removed, but products still not sorted. why?